# Subdomain redirecting to main domain without virtualhost

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a site `sub.example.com` setup in apache with virtualhosts on port 80 and 443 (see configs below). In fact those are the only 2 virtualhosts at all on the server.

However, when I navigate to `sub.example.com`, the browser is redirecting to `example.com`, and even finds the correct document root and renders the login page of `sub.example.come`, where it then gets an ssl error since I only have a certificate for `sub.example.com`.

The first thing I tried was to redirect `example.com` back to `sub.example.com`. I first tried with .htaccess with the Rewrite directives, and it seemed to have no effect. Then I tried setting a permanent redirect in the apache config file, but this resulted in a redirection loop.

How can `sub.example.com` be redirecting to `example.com`, and further, how could `example.com` be finding the document root at all?

Ideally, `example.com` shouldn't exist at all, but I'd be satisfied with it at least redirecting `example.com` to `sub.example.com`.

Here is my apache configuration. (Using ubuntu 12.04 and apache 2.2)

ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80
NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443

Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

virtualhosts configuration

```
# redirect to https
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/webroot
    RedirectPermanent / https://sub.example.com
</VirtualHost>

# https
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    ServerName sub.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/webroot

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/path/to/webroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.crt

    LogLevel notice
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub-example-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub-example-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have put

```
ServerName sub.example.com
```

twice